# Vue component - include css file from Laravel directory

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, less, vuejs2

I am creating a 1 file component in Vue within my Laravel (test) project. But i use less for the css so the css part is in a different file. Now I want to include this file but without any luck. I try to look on stack overflow but am not sure if am searching incorrect or that I am doing something that I am not supposed to do.

[Sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8n1r.png)

What i try to do is

```
<style src="css/sidebar.css"></style>
```

I use the same logic for the image

```
<img class="flex-item" src="img/Home-icon.png">
```

But when i do "npm run dev" I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJoP3.png)

So I thought this maybe wil work:

```
<style src="../public/css/sidebar.css"></style>
```

but then i get the same error but of cours with different path.

So I am a bit lost right now. Anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the relative path from your component file in the project. I use sass, so I use `@import`. Not sure how to import in less. But I show you how I do it in sass.

```
// my-component.vue
<template></template>
<script></script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../../relative/path/to/file.scss";
</style>
```

My example is with Sass. I'm sure you can easily translate it to less.